# Change Azure API App URL from https to http

Tags: azure-api-apps

While creating an Azure API App, by default the URL is https. If I try connecting as http, I get a 302 redirect error. Could you let me know how to change this to http endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is not supported for API apps.

Comment: I've deployed an API App and I can access the site on HTTP ... http://myapiapp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: According to the MSDN doc's, App Service does support HTTP ... App Service does not enforce HTTPS, so visitors can still access your app using HTTP. If you want to enforce HTTPS for your app, you can define a rewrite rule in the web.config file for your app